Which DNS Records to Create?
I want to point my IP to a www.domain.com FQDN.
I want to ensure that users that type domain.com will be redirected to www.domain.com
Which DNS records should I create?

DNS doesn't do redirects. You'll need more than a record.

The simplest is to create two A records
A domain.com 11.22.33.44
A www.domain.com 11.22.33.44

You can turn the WWW A record into a CNAME record, but then you need two lookups if someone visits the site under the name in the CNAME. In this case, your records would be
A domain.com 11.22.33.44
CNAME www.domain.com domain.com

Which means, if you want to visit www.domain.com, you really want to go to name.com so go look that one up. I do have to point out that this is really basic stuff, that you should know already before you start posting to this area...

You generally can't change domain.com to a CNAME. This would have to be done in the .com domain itself, and then it wouldn't be able to delegate the domain to another server.

True. I'll edit the answer.
